# Read and write to Access DB with C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I am making a very basic program for a friend of mine that will need a very basic DataBase. I will have about 3 tables at max, I was wondering if it is possible to use access database files easily in C# just like a normal SQL database and if so how? I have seen some tutorials using OLEDB but none really give me a clear way to do things.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ybdbtte(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Have you considered using SQLite? http://www.sqlite.org/

Comment: @Recipe thanks for that, I'm looking into this now. And e4rthdog no I haven't to be honest. Access seemed the best way as I have never used a proper SQL database myself, I am relatively new. Seeing as SQLite is server-less it may be a good alternative though.

Comment: Its a single file db with no installation and you can use either standard ado.net or EF or whatever else you like...

Comment: SQLite is very easy. I would use that.

Comment: Thanks, @e4rthdog I'll use SQLite, thanks for the help!

Comment: @confuto if you want to try also the ORM world you can go with also using Dapper as a simple ORM with SQLite..they work perfectly! http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/sqlite-simple-database-with-dapper/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really go with the Access need but i throw this answer based on the OPs' intention to digg into SQLite.

So i would go for [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) for its simplicity and efficiency.

See these posts on a very fast and easy way to work with SQLite and Entity Framework:

- [GETTING STARTED, USING SQLITE WITH .NET](http://damienbod.wordpress.com/2013/11/14/using-sqlite-with-net/)
- [USING SQLITE WITH ENTITY FRAMEWORK 6 AND THE REPOSITORY PATTERN](http://damienbod.wordpress.com/2013/11/18/using-sqlite-with-entity-framework-6-and-the-repository-pattern/)
- [SQLITE WITH ENTITY FRAMEWORK CODE FIRST AND MIGRATION](http://hintdesk.com/sqlite-with-entity-framework-code-first-and-migration/)
- [Entity Framework 5 on SQLite](http://bricelam.net/2012/10/entity-framework-on-sqlite.html)
- [Portable databases (II): using SQLite with Entity Framework](http://geekswithblogs.net/danielggarcia/archive/2013/12/22/portable-databases-ii-using-sqlite-with-entity-framework.aspx)